# How to inject model first dbcontext?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am using Angular and asp.net core template.

There are a few existing external databases that I need to use. So I ran below command to generate a DbContext from my database.

I am not sure how to inject the DbContext to the application? How to configure IRepository to work with a set of auto-generated DbContexts?

Thank you

> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

Comment: no. I end up with using Ado.NET in my application service layer.

Comment: Can you show relevant code, and what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I checked a sample application on aspnetboiler and there is a configuration for DbContext, have you tried this?

```
using System;
using Abp.Dependency;
using MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyProject.Identity;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MyProject.Tests.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionRegistrar
    {
        public static void Register(IIocManager iocManager)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);

            services.AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase();

            var serviceProvider = WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(iocManager.IocContainer, services);

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyProjectDbContext>();
            builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);

            // This line is for db context registration

            iocManager.IocContainer.Register(
                Component
                    .For<DbContextOptions<MyProjectDbContext>>()
                    .Instance(builder.Options)
                    .LifestyleSingleton()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Herzl, thanks for your answer. But my question is specific to aspnetboilerplate framework.

Comment: I'm reading your question in second time and I have not found boiler template in question, but do you have checked this ? https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection

Comment: I have an abp tag in the question. I know how to inject general application services with interfaces but not sure how to inject dbcontext.

Comment: Just to make sure, ef core ?